# How can I sort my Wordpress posts by certain criteria (i.e. random, recent posts, custom fields, ect.)?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, menu, switch-statement, toggle

I need to create a menu to sort my posts by most recent, random, ect. and I have not found anything online that would work for me. I want a menu like this:

```
<div class="sort">
   <a class="recent" href="?sort=recent">Recent</a>
   <a class="random" href="?sort=random">Random</a>
</div>
```

And then be able to change the output of the page by clicking on the menu links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and searched and couldn't find anything that would work for my project; then it dawned on me: switch statements.

Creating a simple menu:

```
<div class="sort">
   <a class="recent" href="?sort=recent">Recent</a>
   <a class="random" href="?sort=random">Random</a>
</div>
```

And add the switch statements:

```
$order = 'ASC';
$orderby = '';

switch ($_GET['sort']) {
    case 'recent':
        $order = 'DESC';
        $orderby = '';
        break;
    case 'random':
        $orderby = 'rand';
        break;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'entry',
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => 20, // limit of posts
    'orderby' => $orderby,
);
```

Then do the loop like normal. This can work for custom fields too!

```
'meta_key' => $metakey,    
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 'customfield'
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to solving the issue when you have at most one querystring parameter to handle.

Comment: Yes, I only needed it for one query-string parameter because the users clicks on the menu to toggle between the posts sorts. Thanks!